# Not able to calculate gradient at given point in an image while applying inpainting algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, gradient, derivative

I'm trying to implement an inpainting algorithm from a research paper by Criminisi (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-2003-84.pdf). So I cannot use MATLAB's builtin function for the same. I'm not able to proceed as I stuck at a step for which I'm not getting the correct result. The term which I'm not able to calculate correctly is this

[image]

[image]

Initialization code

```
originalImage = imread("fig 1.jpg");
mask = imread("fig 1 target.jpg"); % white represent target region

% Converting original image and mask to grayscale
[row, column, channel] = size(originalImage);
% converting to grayscale images
if channel > 1
    I = rgb2gray(originalImage);
else
    I = originalImage;
end

[~,~,channel] = size(mask);
if channel > 1
    mask = rgb2gray(mask);
end

% Finding edges on mask which will 
% return bounded boundary
maskBoundary = edge(mask, 'Canny');

% Finding boundary points of target region
[boundaryY, boundaryX] = find(maskBoundary);

% Binary mask of target(Omega) and source(Phi) region
omega = imbinarize(mask,0.1);
phi = ~omega;

% source region
source = originalImage.*uint8(phi);

% Edges on source image
sourceEdges = edge(I, 'canny').*phi;
% imshow(sourceEdges);
% Magnitude and direction of source image
[sMag, sDir] = imgradient(rgb2gray(source), 'sobel');
% Gradient in x and y direction
[sGx, sGy] = imgradientxy(rgb2gray(source));

% Confidence matrix
% source pixels confidence = 1
% target pixels confidence = 0 (initially)
confidence = double(phi);

% defining the patch size
texelSize = 9;
texelSize_half = (texelSize-1)/2;

% Confidence and data term along target boundary
confidence_i = zeros(size(boundaryX));
data_i = zeros(size(boundaryX));
% unitVector normal to target region boundary
unitVector_i = zeros(2,1);
```

Loop where I'm calculating stated term

```
for index=2:size(boundaryY,1)-1
    Confidence_val = 0.0;
    Grad_val = 0.0;
    
    % confidence calculation
    confidence_i(index) = sum( ...
        confidence(boundaryY(index)-texelSize_half:boundaryY(index)+texelSize_half, ...
        boundaryX(index)-texelSize_half:boundaryX(index)+texelSize_half),'all')/texelSize^2;
    
    i = index;
    px = boundaryX(i); % column
    py = boundaryY(i); % row
    % gradient vector (rotated) at point p(px,py)
    gradPx = -sGy(py,px);
    gradPy = sGx(py,px);
    
    
    % Unit matrix normal to target region boundary
    tangent = [boundaryX(i+1)-boundaryX(i-1); boundaryY(i+1)-boundaryY(i-1)];
    vectorMod = sqrt((boundaryX(i+1)-boundaryX(i-1))^2 + (boundaryY(i+1)-boundaryY(i-1))^2);
    
    unitVector_i(1) = -tangent(2)/vectorMod;
    unitVector_i(2) = tangent(1)/vectorMod;
    nPx = unitVector_i(1);
    nPy = unitVector_i(2);
    
    data_i(i) = abs(dot([gradPx,gradPy],[nPx,nPy]))/255;
end
```

I don't have much experience in image processing so I don't understand some of the terms well. Can someone please rectify the problem or refer me to its MATLAB/OpenCV implementation.

---

The current status of my code is here including example images

https://github.com/lkdhruw/inpainting_exercise

---

Found this implementation on GitHub, which somewhat difficult for me to follow and also didn't work on my MATLAB 2020b

https://github.com/ikuwow/inpainting_criminisi2004

---

I've checked out the following links

[What is an Image Gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911127/what-is-an-image-gradient)

[Image gradient in the point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067303/image-gradient-in-the-point)

[Calculating image gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842844/calculating-image-gradient)

[image gradient angle computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106748/image-gradient-angle-computation)

[Patch priority and its effect on Criminsi's Exemplar Based Inpainting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374117/patch-priority-and-its-effect-on-criminsis-exemplar-based-inpainting)

---

**EDIT**

**Problem**

[image]

I'm facing the problem calculating the data term `D(p)`. See image labeled 1, there is only one intensity change, so according to the algorithm the priority term `P(p) = C(p) D(p)` should have one peak at that location. The problem is there are multiple peaks that too at very far from each other. I've mentioned only the data term (fig label 3) because the output is very similar to the priority term (fig label 4). Can someone please find out whether I've calculated the `D(p)` correctly or not?

Comment: You keep refering to a problem, but never actually say what it is. Do you get an error?

Comment: @MatteoV There is no runtime error but there is some incorrect output (now added in question). I know the expected output `D(p)` as per the algorithm but the output is quite confusing. I am not an expert on this to figure it by myself whether I have done it correctly or not. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I wouldn't really be looking at those single peaks, as they're most likely artefacts. Perhaps due to the fact that the direction of the normal vector is changing abruptly from one pixel to the other? Anyway, if you look at your image 3 as a curve with some noise on it, it does seem to have a small bump around 200-205, and a bigger one at around 70? So the question you should be asking yourself is (probably) why do you get the latter.